# How to transform to regular columns a list of dictionary field in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in postgresl 14 table that is a list of dictionary with 4 keys like this:

```
[{"id": 14771, "stock": "alfa-12", "name": "rooftop", "store": "MI"}, 
 {"id": 14700, "stock": "beta-10", "name": "stove", "store": "UK"}]
```

This list can contain dozens of dicts but they all have `id, stock, name and store` as keys.

Is there a way to query this field and get it as regular columns like this:

```
id      stock     name       store
14771   alfa-12   rooftop     MI
14700   beta-10   stove       UK
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` to get all elements of the json array and `jsonb_to_record()` to convert the elements to records. Read about the functions in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```sql
select id, name, stock, store
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_col)
cross join jsonb_to_record(value) as t(id int, name text, stock text, store text)
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/O3mZmAVh)